# Change marker shape in Splunk line chart

Tags: splunk

Though it's weirdly not in the UI, I can enable markers on a line chart with:

```
<option name="charting.chart.showMarkers">true</option>
```

[image]

However, if there are multiple series, it's nice to have different marker shapes (square, triangle, etc.) on each series. Is this possible to do on a Splunk line chart?

Answer (score 0):

The marker is binary, either it is or it's not. What can be changed is the style of the dash

For example if you have two series antena3 and digi24 you can apply the following to make one series dotted and the other short-dotted:

```
<option name="charting.fieldDashStyles">{"antena3":"shortDot", "digi24":"shortDash"}</option>
```

it will look like this:

[image]

Complete chart config reference: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/ChartConfigurationReference#General_chart_properties